# RedirectMatch appending Query String

Tags: apache-2.2

I've got some RedirectMatch statements to redirect old urls to the new documents, but for some reason they're working properly, except that it's appending the initial request url as a query string. Eg. Requesting

`http://www.domain.com/filename.html`

redirects to

`http://www.domain.com/new_filename.html?/filename.html`

The corresponding rule would be:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/filename.html$ http://www.domain.com/new_filename.html`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't require RedirectMatch; use a simple Redirect:

`Redirect permanent /filename.html http://www.domain.com/new_filename.mhtml`

Remember that Redirect works on URLs, not paths.